# Python Webscrape: hidden strange url link that is not available in page source

Tags: python, pdf, sharepoint

I am currently working on extracting some information from a portal. What I am trying to do is to extract the url link to an external PDF file. The Website I am trying to scrape is https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/800. The information I am trying to scrape is the BIS Decision Memo sectio with a button "View attachment file" linked to an external PDF file

["View attachment file" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtZS8.png)

Here comes the question: when I looked into the page source, I did not find any url link related to the PDF file:

```
                    <div>
                        <h3>BIS Decision Memo</h3>
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <div class="row form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12" id="DMAttachment">
                                    <span>Please wait...</span>
                                    <a href="" data-id="800" data-type="DM">View attachment file</a><br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-left">
```

However, when clicked on the "View attachment file" button, I was able to download the PDF file. I look into my download path with the PDF file, I found that the link address to the PDF file is as follows:

https://itaisinternationaltrade.sharepoint.com/sites/232App/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=a18de65a-7092-4670-8c9a-9315a62f1814&Translate=false&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.R2FXb3pYOE4yN1VFajRRMUs3ME50QlZjdHZ6ZnljNSs4VFlQaUhiQitYRT0&ApiVersion=2.0

Therefore, I am very curious in where does this strange url come from. I split this strange url into several parts and search them one by one from the page source, but I could not get any clues. Therefore, I would like to ask for some hints on how to get this url.

In addition, I am trying to scrape more PDF url links like the above one: https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/801
Therefore, I would like to ask if there is any way that I can scrape these PDF file links? How should I approach this question? What I have right now is to use the requests package:

```
import requests
url = 'https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/800'
html_data = requests.get(url).text
```

Then I tried to slice the text to extract the PDF url. However, since I am not able to find the PDF urls from above, so I do not know what I can do. Please give me some hints. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: page may use JavaScript to generate this url, or original url may load page which redirect you to this url (ie. after checking if you have all privilages and you are not bot)

Comment: first assign `response = requests.get(url)` and then you can check `response.url` and `response.history` - it should shows you if original url was redirected

Comment: @furas Thank you very much for your comment! Running `response = requests.get(url)` followed by `response.url` gives me the original url 'https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/800, but not the url to the PDF file

Comment: I checked button `"View attachment file"` on page using `DevTools` in `Firefox` and it shows that it has assigned `event` - and it means it runs `JavaScript` when you click it in web brower. But `requests` can't run javaScript and you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real webbrowers which can run JavaScript.

Comment: I found that this JavaScript send requests to `https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/800?handler=DownloadDM&ID=800` and this gives url to PDF. maybe you could use it with `requests` to get url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page use JavaScript when you click this button.

Using `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (and digging in `HTML`) I found that this button sends request to ur

https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/800?handler=DownloadDM&ID=800

and it gets JSON data with link to PDF.

SO I used this to get file using only `requests`

```
import requests
import webbrowser

number = 800

# generate URL with `800` in two places
url = f'https://232app.azurewebsites.net/Forms/ExclusionRequestItem/{number}?handler=DownloadDM&ID={number}'

# send requests to get JSON data with `data["downloadURL"]`
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

print('url:', data["downloadURL"])

# create unique filename for PDF
filename = f'output-{number}.pdf'

# get PDF and save in file (usign bytes mode)
r = requests.get(data["downloadURL"])
with open(filename, 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)

# open PDF in default program 
webbrowser.open(filename)
```

Using different number I can get different documents.

Comment: so now you can mark my answer as accepted, and later you can upvote it.

Comment: by the way: I put this code on blog [Python: How to download PDF on US Department of Commerce using requests.](https://blog.furas.pl/python-scraping-how-to-download-pdf-on-us-department-of-commerce-using-requests-gb.html) and maybe later I put it also on GIthub in [python-examples / scraping](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__)